# Filter the kendo schedular based on the date range in jquery (client side)

Tags: jquery, date, kendo-ui, filtering, scheduler

I have kendo schedular in my page and I loaded it with events while page is loading. Now I have 2 text boxes(start and end dates) which have kendo date pickers. So when I select dates and hit submit I need to filter the schedular with the date range. Calendar should show the events within the date range only.

This filtering should be done on client side.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible approaches for achieving this behavior (**you can even combine them** depending on your requirements):

1. Create **custom view that extends the desired build-in one** and overriding the methods responsible for calculating the visible date range. Such demo can be found [here (link)](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/view-with-custom-date-range-and-swipe-support).
2. Filter the events by their start/end date on the server side as shown in [this demo (link)](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/kendoui-scheduler-server-filtering).